# calculations between a matrix and a vector without for loops in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix and a vector:

```
set.seed(999)
mat = matrix(round(rnorm(24,4,9)),3,8)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    6  -13   -6   12   -8   12   10
[2,]   -8    2   -7   16    6    5  -15    1
[3,]   11   -1   -5    5   13    5   -7    7

vec = c(1,5, 4,4, 2,1, 4,8)
```

Now I hope to calculate, for each row of `mat`, the distances between that row and the `vec` with two elements as a "group". For example, I want to have

```
d11 = |mat[1,1:2] - vec[1:2]|
d12 = |mat[1,3:4] - vec[3:4]|
d13 = |mat[1,5:6] - vec[5:6]|
d14 = |mat[1,7:8] - vec[7:8]|
```

The same thing is done for the rest of the rows of `mat` (i.e. rows 2 and 3) to have `d21,...,d24, d31,...,d34`.

I hope that this task can be done without using for loops. Is there any function that is directly usable for this goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works:

```
s1 <- sweep(mat,2,vec,"-")  ## subtract vec
s2 <- s1^2                  ## square
s3 <- cbind(s2[col(s2) %% 2 ==1],s2[col(s2) %% 2 ==0])  ## stack
s4 <- rowSums(s3)
s5 <- matrix(s4,nrow=3)  ## restack
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1  389  181   68
## [2,]   90  265   32  410
## [3,]  136   82  137  122
```

There might be a better way to do step 3, but the rest seems close to optimal.  (You could probably speed up step 1 slightly as `t(t(mat)-vec)`, but I prefer `sweep` for readability.)